# Dual monitors stopped working DVI-I DVI-D Nvidia GTX 960 Windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, nvidia-geforce

Windows 10 Home 64

Nvidia GeForce GTX 960 v373.06, two monitor ports; one DVI-I and one DVI-D (both dual links).

2 x Benq GW2320 LCD monitors connected with DVI-D cables, monitor 1 running 1920x1080 @ 60Hz

Dual monitors were working fine on this set up.
Moved box to different location where I used single HDMI monitor for a day.
Came back, and now only whichever monitor is plugged in to the DVI-I port is working.

When I plug either of the monitors into the DVI-D port, that monitor screen does change from ‘No cable connected’ to ‘no signal’ but nothing more before going to sleep.

Have rolled back drivers, reinstalled to latest version.
I looked in BIOS but saw nothing obvious.
I’ve tried Windows Project, Control Panel → Display, which has no acknowledgement of the 2nd monitor.
Have tried 'Rigorous Display Detection' and 'Force television detection' from the Nvidia control panel, none of which can detect the display.

Any ideas? Or further tests to rule out things?

TIA

edit: have tried reseating graphics card
edit: screen attached via HDMI not receiving signal either

Comment: Because you moved the box, you may want to re-seat the card (take it out of the PCIE slot and put it back in).  This will also cause you to have to totally reinstall the video driver, so it would be good to have it downloaded already.

Comment: Have reseated card - which incidentally did not require reinstall of the driver – with no effect.
Also, the machine is no longer recognising a HDMI screen attached to either the HDMI slot on the graphics card nor the machine HDMI slot.